# Ruby on Rails: only get, put, and delete allowed

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My view:

```
<h1>New Address</h1>

<% form_for @address, :url => new_address_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  <%= render :partial => "form", :object => f %>
  <%= f.submit "Add Address" %>
<% end %>
```

Partial... nothing special

```
<%= form.label :number %><br />
<%= form.text_field :number %><br />
<br />
<%= form.label :street %><br />
<%= form.text_field :street %><br />
<br />
<%= form.label :city %><br />
<%= form.text_field :city %><br />
<br />
<%= form.label :state %><br />
<%= form.text_field :state %><br />
<br />
<%= form.label :zip_code %><br />
<%= form.text_field :zip_code %><br />
<br />
<br />
```

my error:

```
ActionController::MethodNotAllowed

Only get, put, and delete requests are allowed.
```

Comment: Please post your routes.rb and controller, the problem is likely in one of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MethodNotAllowed` seems to come from resource-based routing. Resource-based routing requires distinct method names to match actions. In your case, you should supply `:method => :post` in `form_for`, something like that:
`<% form_for @address, new_address_path, :method => :post) do |f| -%>`